# Getting the Correct version of the Oracle Driver in Groovy

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, groovy

I have a groovy script that connects to an Oracle database, performs a query, then writes the contents to a CSV file.

I'm connecting to the database like this:

```
def db = [url:connectionUrl, driver:"oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", user:connectionUser, password:connectionPassword]
sql = Sql.newInstance(db)
```

The trouble is, my query is complex, and relies on a particular version of the Oracle JDBC driver to be in use.

On my machine, I have ojdbc6.jar (the version of the oracle jdbc driver) that I need in my classpath ($GROOVY_HOME/lib/). It loads fine, and the script works.

When I check the driver version...

```
println "Oracle JDBC Driver used: ${sql.getConnection().getMetaData().getDriverVersion()}" //Should be 11.x for this script to work
```

...the script says it's using 11.2.0.1.0.

On a remote host, where our job scheduling software lives, I have a similar setup- ojdbc6.jar is in the $GROOVY_HOME/lib folder. However, when the script runs, it's reporting using Oracle Driver 9.2.0.6.0.

**How can I specify the version of the Oracle JDBC driver to use when building my connection?**

## What I've Tried

Using the java.sql.DriverManager class, I've tried to enumerate the drivers available to my script:

```
DriverManager.getDrivers().toList().each{
    println it
    println it?.majorVersion        
    println it?.minorVersion        
}
```

On my machine, that outputs:

> oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver@5ff8cef
>
> 11
>
> 2

On the job scheduling server, I get:

> sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver@a7e0a7e
>
> 2
>
> 1

How do I tell Java/Groovy "Use *this* jdbc, and not that one?"

Comment: This sounds like a classpath issue.  Sounds like you need to get the classpath ordered so ojdbc6.jar is at the front of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a classpath issue. Try to locate the jar containing oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver class in the runtime.

You can use the following statement:

```
println oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver.class.protectionDomain.codeSource.location.path
```

It will show the path to the jar used to load the Oracle driver. This will probably be different to your required jar.

You can get the whole classpath from a system property:

```
System.getProperty("java.class.path")
```

Comment: Ultimately, I decided it was best just to put my complex query in a view in the Oracle database, then select * from that in my Groovy script.